# proguard: keep method with a list of parameters

Tags: proguard

Try to keep a method with multiple parameters

```
public class Foo {

    public static void sayHello(Object v1, String v2) {
       ...
    }

}
```

proguard conf:

```
-keep class Foo {

    void sayHello(***);
}
```

Not working. How to specify a list of parameters?  `***` not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match multiple parameter types you need to use:

```
-keep class Foo {
    void sayHello(...);
}
```

`***` will only match a single parameter (but accept all possible types). Also take a look at the ProGuard manual that explains it quite well: [ProGuard manual, Class Specification](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#classspecification)